# oracle сервер не понимает русскую кодировку

Tags: oracle

Сервер *Oracle* не понимает кириллицу. Ни при вставке данных в таблицу, ни при компиляции процедур с русскими комментариями.

Вместо русских символов везде пишет вопросы "????". Разработка ведется в *PL/sql developer* с одного удаленного терминала несколькими разработчиками.

**Проблема возникла только у одного нового разработчика.**

Проверил *CHARACTERSET* на сервере *Oracle* (12 версия).

```
select * from sys.V_$NLS_VALID_VALUES v where v.PARAMETER = 'CHARACTERSET';  

PARAMETER       VALUE           ISDEPRECATED    CON_ID
...
CHARACTERSET    WE8MSWIN1252    FALSE           0
...
```

Проверил *nls_lang* на клиенте:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient12Home1_32bit
NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: текущая кодировка = "AL32UTF8" (select * from v$nls_parameters s where s.PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET')

Comment: У меня в `HLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251` Тоже самое и в других поддиректориях этой ветки реестра. Может это поможет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрос строки из БД выводит нечитабельные символы вместо кириллических](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956206/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85)

Answer (score 1):

Была на одной машине такая проблема, решалась выполнением следующего *.reg файла

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
"1250"="c_1251.nls"
"1251"="c_1251.nls"
"1252"="c_1251.nls"
```