# Запрос строки из БД выводит нечитабельные символы вместо кириллических

Tags: sql, oracle, кодировка, клиент

Пытаюсь в клиентской программе с помощью запроса к БД:

```
select 'АБВГДЕЙКА' from dual;
```

вывести кирилические символы, но получаю или:

> ??????????????????

, или квадратики, а так-же другие кракозябры.

Какие пути решения проблемы?

Answer (score 15):

TL;DR Почти без исключений проблема кроется в различных кодировках (*charachter set*) установленных в программе-клиенте (далее клиент) и в БД.

Если кодировки не совпадают, то после получения символьных данных из БД в клиенте производится неявная перекодировка этих данных из кодировки установленной в БД в кодировку установленную в клиенте. Неверно установленная кодировка в клиенте приведёт к неверному отображению символов.

Тоже самое действет для другого направления, т.е. для записи в БД.

---

**Когда перекодировка в кириллицу возможна?**

Если кодировка в клиенте является [подмножеством кодировки в БД](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/nlspg/choosing-character-set.html#GUID-B8A1BDEC-7992-41E1-B10C-F141479EAD35), т.е. все символы кодировки на клиенте содержаться в кодировке БД. Например, если в БД установлены:

- `US7ASCII` (только 7-ь бит), `EE8MSWIN1250` или `EE8ISO8859P2` 
  (восточноевропейские языки) и подобные им, то перекодировка невозможна.
- Многосимвольные кодировки: `AL32UTF8`, `AL16UTF16` и т.п. - не должны вызывать проблем.

**Как узнать, какая кодировка установлена в БД?**

```
select value 
from nls_database_parameters 
where parameter = upper ('nls_characterset');
```

**Как установить нужную кодировку в клиенте?**

Зависит собственно от клиента, но в большинстве случаев, т.к. используют одни и те же библиотеки доступа к БД (OCI, JDBC), действуют установки в следующей последовательности (последовательность важна, из нескольких последняя выиграет):

- **(Только Windows)** в реестре:

  ```
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_[Client_home1]: NLS_LANG=.CL8MSWIN1251
  ```
- В переменной окружения `NLS_LANG`

  - WIN:  `Свойствa системы -> Дополнительно -> Переменные среды`
    или в командном интерпретере: `set NLS_LANG=.CL8MSWIN1251`
  - UNIX: `~/.profile`
    или в терминале: `export NLS_LANG=.CL8MSWIN1251`
- Программа-клиент может иметь свои собственные установки, которые перепишут все выше описанные.

Значение `NLS_LANG` состоит из 3-х независимых друг-от-друга частей и имеет форму:   `language_territory.characterset`, например `NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_RUSSIA.CL8MSWIN1251`.
В данной теме интересна последняя часть после точки.

**Кодировка в клиенте установлена правильно, но увы, куда смотреть дальше?**

- В программе или терминале не установлена поддержка кириллических символов.

  - WIN: в командном интерпретере вывод `chcp` совпадает с желаемой кодировкой? 
    Попробуйте изменить, например: `chcp 1251`
  - UNIX: проверте переменную окружения: `env | grep LANG`
  - В программе могут быть специальные установки для поддержки различных кодировок, например в SQL Developer:

    ```
    Preferences -> (+) Environment -> Encoding: [ ... ]
    ```
- Установленный шрифт не поддерживает кириллические символы. Попробуйте заменить шрифт по-умолчанию.
- Кодировка в клиенте изменнена после того, как с предедущей кодировкой были произведены операци изменения (или вставки). Все измененые в БД данные, содержащие кириллические символы - "мусор". Удалите изменения и повторите их после установки правильной кодировки в клиенте.

Подробнее в [офф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/nlspg/choosing-character-set.html#GUID-BF26E01D-AB92-48FC-855A-69A5B3AF9A92).

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло установка environment variables

> NLS_LANG = RUSSIAN.CL8MSWIN1251

Но это недостаточно - в установках языка
Administrative Language Settings нужно такое установить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]