# Работа функции NEXT_DAY на разных языках

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
    product_id "PRODUKT",
    NEXT_DAY(restock_date, 'Пятница') "PIATEK PO DOSTAWI",
    LAST_DAY(restock_date) "OSTATNI DZIEN MIESIACA"
FROM inventory
WHERE restock_date IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY restock_date;
```

В данном случае `NEXT_DAY()` работает только на компьютерах с русским языком.

Как сделать, чтобы  функция  работала на всех  языках, например на польском?

Comment: Как вы понимаете эту фразу: "на компьютерах с русской локализацией"?

Comment: прошу  прощение  не  поставил  корректно  вопрос , я имел  ввиду  , что  интерфейс  операционной системы на русском языке

Comment: Хм, пока не вижу никакой связи между вашим вопросом и  интерфейсом операционной системы. Что вы пробуете и что не получается?

Comment: Задача заключается в  том, что  мне  нужно  добавить  к  дате (restock_date) что  была  пятница. Во  втором параметре  функции  NEXT_DAY  я указал  на  русском 'пятница'  , так  как  у  меня windwos  на русском . Когда я пытался написать  'Friday'   вместо пятницы ,то выбила ошибка и я пришел  к выводу что это  функция не  будет  работать  у кого  winwos  на  английском или  другом языке . Хотелось  бы что бы  функция работала  независимо  от  языка

Comment: простыми словами есть  один компьютер  на русском  языке  и  другой  на  польском  языке  , как  сделать  что  бы  функция работала  на двух компьютерах

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Решающим является установка языка в клиенте где вы вызываете запрос, а не интерфейс операционной системы.

```
alter session set nls_language='polish';
```

Теперь по-русски не будет работать:

```
select next_day (date'2019-03-16', 'Пятница') "Next Fr." from dual;
```

> ORA-01846: niepoprawny dzień tygodnia
>   01846. 00000 -  "not a valid day of the week"

А по-польски будет:

```
select next_day (date'2019-03-16', 'Piątek') "Next Fr." from dual;
```

> 2019-03-22 00:00:00

Как установить нужный язык в клиенте, не прибегая к `alter session ...`, можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956206/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85/956207#956207) (в данном случае интересна 1-я составляющая `NLS_LANG=language`). Подробнее в [офф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/NLS_LANGUAGE.html#GUID-0DD64F19-BEF2-4B4B-A232-3BA3F8494949), если останутся вопросы.