# Почему язык результата функции TO_CHAR отличается?

Tags: sql, delphi, oracle

Если выполнить запрос из *SQL Developer*

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DY') from dual
```

то результат `ВТ`, т.е. по русски.

Eсли выполнить этот же запрос из моей программы на *Delphi*, то возвращает `TUE` (Tuesday).

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: У вас установлены разные языки. [Связаный вопрос:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/957332/217579).

Answer (score 2):

*SQL Developer*  делает для этого не так много. Если произвести поиск в *Statemnets Log* на "set NLS", то без труда будет найдена такая строчка:

```
alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE='RUSSIAN'
```

Вызовите в программе это предложение сразу же после соединения с БД, и всё будет работать:

```
select to_char (sysdate, 'DY') day from dual;

DAY     
--------
ВТ
```