# Кириллица в названии столбца

Tags: sql, oracle, кириллица

Подрядчик предоставляет БД, из которой нужно вытягивать данные.
Проблема в том что не выходит использовать в заголовке киррилицу, вместо нее получаем "¿¿¿¿¿".
В результатах запроса кириллица нормально отображается, поэтому есть подозрение что в названии колонок ее тоже использовать возможно.

например, запрос:

```
select item_description as "Описание изделия" from items
```

возвращает вот это:

[image]

Переменная среды NLS_LANG прописана (RUSSIAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251).
Кодировка базы - WE8MSWIN1252

(получено запросом

```
select value 
from nls_database_parameters 
where parameter = upper ('nls_characterset')
```

)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли вообще как-то вывести кириллицу в заголовок в таком случае (доступа к модификации настроек БД нет)? Если да, то что для этого нужно сделать? .

upd: запрос `select item as ы from items` выдает следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делайте это средствами клиента, выводящего результат запроса... и на всякий случай посмотрите NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрос строки из БД выводит нечитабельные символы вместо кириллических](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956206/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85)

Comment: Нет, кирилицу вы не сможете использовать. Кодировка WE8MSWIN1252 
 содержит только латиницу и CL8MSWIN1251 с ней несовместима.

Answer (score 0):

Пропиши вот это AMERICAN_CIS.CL8MSWIN1251, вот эту кодировку надо прописать в реестре в ветвь: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавте пожалуйста в ответ кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1016545/217579) - Что это, и куда это прописать?

Comment: Но у ТС таже в вопросе указана таже кодировка. Почему вы думаете, что это поможет?

Comment: @0xdb, наверное прописывать в переменные среды)

Comment: @user284221, у меня в реестре вообще ветви ORACLE нет по этому адресу, только ODBC но там NLS не нашел...

Comment: @VargGrimmson Если у вас возник новый вопрос, то задайте его [этой кнопкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).