# Не отображается кириллица при отправке почты через UTL_SMTP

Tags: oracle, кодировка, plsql, oracle19c

имеется следующий триггер, который отправляет сообщение с html содержимым в виде таблицы, с почтового ящика mail.ru на почтовый ящик gmail.com.Все сообщения, доходят, но к сожалению не корректно отображаются русские символы в виде, например "‘¥à¨©­ë© ­®¬¥à ". Кодировка базы данных AL32UTF8. При смене кодировки в заголовке письма Content-Type: text/html;charset= и использовании функции CONVERT(),например Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1251 и CONVERT(message,'CL8MSWIN1251') тоже нечего не меняется.Собственно, хотелось бы понять, это проблема в самом триггере или на стороне почтового клиента и зависит от почтового клиента. Как я понимаю, в charset= надо указывать ту кодировку, в какой у меня база данных.Но если я просто отправляю данные и ставлю кодировку utf-8, то тоже нечего не меняется.Как отправить данные в правильной кодировке? Спасибо.

```
create or replace trigger Cartridge_repair after update of "Состояние_картриджа" 
on "Картриджи"
declare
CURSOR cur_query IS SELECT DECODE(ctr,1,tb1."Название_картриджа",NULL) AS "Название_картриджа",DECODE(ctr,1,tb1."Серийный_номер",NULL) AS "Серийный_номер",DECODE(ctr,1,tb1."Необходимость_в_повторной_заправке",NULL) AS "Необходимость_в_повторной_заправке",DECODE(ctr,1,tb1."Цвет_печати_картриджа",NULL) AS "Цвет_печати_картриджа",DECODE(ctr,1,tb1."Cостояние_заправки_картриджа",NULL) AS "Cостояние_заправки_картриджа",DECODE(ctr,1,tb1."Признаки_неисправности_картриджа(если_картридж_неисправен)",NULL) AS "Признаки_неисправности_картриджа",DECODE(ctr,1,tb1."Причина_неисправности_картриджа(если_картридж_неисправен)",NULL) AS "Причина_неисправности_картриджа",tb1."Название_устройства" AS "Совместимые_устройства",tb1."Тип_устройства" AS "Тип_устройства" FROM (SELECT tb."Название_картриджа",tb."Серийный_номер",tb."Цвет_печати_картриджа",tb."Необходимость_в_повторной_заправке",tb."Cостояние_заправки_картриджа",tb."Признаки_неисправности_картриджа(если_картридж_неисправен)",tb."Причина_неисправности_картриджа(если_картридж_неисправен)","Офисная_техника"."Название_устройства","Офисная_техника"."Тип_устройства", ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tb."Название_картриджа" ORDER BY NULL) AS ctr FROM (SELECT "Картриджи"."Название_картриджа","Картриджи"."Серийный_номер","Картриджи"."Цвет_печати_картриджа","Картриджи"."Необходимость_в_повторной_заправке","Картриджи"."Cостояние_заправки_картриджа",
"Картриджи"."Признаки_неисправности_картриджа(если_картридж_неисправен)","Картриджи"."Причина_неисправности_картриджа(если_картридж_неисправен)" FROM "Картриджи" WHERE "Картриджи"."Состояние_картриджа"='не исправен' and ("Картриджи"."Текущее_местоположение_картриджа"='в устройстве' or "Картриджи"."Текущее_местоположение_картриджа"='на складе')) tb,"Офисная_техника" JOIN "Совместимо_с" ON "Офисная_техника"."Серийный_номер"="Совместимо_с"."Серийный_номер_устройства" WHERE tb."Серийный_номер"="Совместимо_с"."Серийный_номер_картриджа") tb1 where tb1."Серийный_номер" NOT IN (select * from list_snc);
CURSOR cur_query_def_car IS SELECT * FROM tbl_def_car;
rec1 cur_query%ROWTYPE;
rec2 cur_query_def_car%ROWTYPE;
nls_charset varchar2(255 char);
message clob;
tbl_content clob;                                                                                     
mail_conn utl_smtp.connection;
numb_def NUMBER;
begin
if parameter_values.get_val('send_mail_rep_car')='Y' then
select * into numb_def from count_numb_def_car;
OPEN cur_query;
LOOP 
FETCH cur_query INTO rec1;
EXIT WHEN cur_query%NOTFOUND;
if rec1."Серийный_номер" is not null then
insert into list_snc values(rec1."Серийный_номер");
numb_def:=numb_def+1;
end if;
tbl_content:=tbl_content||'<tr><td>'||rec1."Название_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Серийный_номер"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Необходимость_в_повторной_заправке"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Цвет_печати_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Cостояние_заправки_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Признаки_неисправности_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Причина_неисправности_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Совместимые_устройства"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Тип_устройства"||'</td></tr>';
if numb_def<>parameter_values.get_val('numb_def') then
insert into tbl_def_car values('<tr><td>'||rec1."Название_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Серийный_номер"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Необходимость_в_повторной_заправке"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Цвет_печати_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Cостояние_заправки_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Признаки_неисправности_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Причина_неисправности_картриджа"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Совместимые_устройства"||'</td><td>'||rec1."Тип_устройства"||'</td></tr>');
end if;
END LOOP;
update count_numb_def_car set numb=numb_def;
IF cur_query%ROWCOUNT!=0 and numb_def=parameter_values.get_val('numb_def') THEN
update count_numb_def_car set numb=0;
if parameter_values.get_val('numb_def')=1 then
message:= parameter_values.get_val('temp_repair')||tbl_content||'</table></body></html>';
else
OPEN cur_query_def_car;
LOOP
FETCH cur_query_def_car INTO rec2;
EXIT WHEN cur_query_def_car%NOTFOUND;
tbl_content:=tbl_content||rec2.tbl_content;      
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_query_def_car;
message:= parameter_values.get_val('temp_repair')||tbl_content||'</table></body></html>';
delete from tbl_def_car;
end if;
IF parameter_values.get_val('encrypt')='Y' THEN
mail_conn:= utl_smtp.open_connection(host =>parameter_values.get_val('outgoing_server'),port=>parameter_values.get_val('port'),wallet_path=>parameter_values.get_val('path_wallet'),wallet_password=>parameter_values.get_val('pass_wallet'),secure_connection_before_smtp=>true);
ELSE
mail_conn:= utl_smtp.open_connection(host =>parameter_values.get_val('outgoing_server'),port=>parameter_values.get_val('port'));
END IF;
utl_smtp.ehlo(mail_conn,parameter_values.get_val('outgoing_server'));
utl_smtp.auth(mail_conn,parameter_values.get_val('login_smtp'),parameter_values.get_val('pass_smtp'),utl_smtp.ALL_SCHEMES);
utl_smtp.mail(mail_conn,parameter_values.get_val('sender'));
utl_smtp.rcpt(mail_conn,parameter_values.get_val('recipient'));
utl_smtp.open_data(mail_conn);
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Date: ' || to_char(sysdate,'dd Mon yy hh24:mi:ss','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN')||UTL_TCP.crlf));
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('From: ' || parameter_values.get_val('sender')||UTL_TCP.crlf));
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('To: '||parameter_values.get_val('recipient')||UTL_TCP.crlf));
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Subject: '||NVL('Test','(no subject)')||UTL_TCP.crlf));
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('MIME-Version: 1.0' ||UTL_TCP.crlf));
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8' ||UTL_TCP.crlf));
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' ||UTL_TCP.crlf));
IF parameter_values.get_val('cc') IS NOT NULL THEN
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Cc: '||parameter_values.get_val('cc')||UTL_TCP.crlf));
END IF;
IF parameter_values.get_val('bcc') IS NOT NULL THEN
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn,utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Bcc: '||parameter_values.get_val('bcc')||UTL_TCP.crlf));
END IF;
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(mail_conn,UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(message));
utl_smtp.close_data(mail_conn);
utl_smtp.quit(mail_conn);
END IF;
CLOSE cur_query;
end if;
if parameter_values.get_val('auto_change_loc_def_car')='Y' then
update "Картриджи" SET "Картриджи"."Текущее_устройство_в_котором_установлен_картридж"=NULL,"Картриджи"."Текущее_местоположение_картриджа"='требуется ремонт' WHERE "Картриджи"."Состояние_картриджа"='не исправен' and ("Картриджи"."Текущее_местоположение_картриджа"='в устройстве' or "Картриджи"."Текущее_местоположение_картриджа"='на складе');
end if;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
utl_smtp.quit(mail_conn);
end;
/
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, составте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 90% кода в вопросе с ошибкой никак не связаны.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрос строки из БД выводит нечитабельные символы вместо кириллических](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956206/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85)

Answer (score 2):

Вот так работает:

```sql
declare 
    rcpt varchar2 (128) := 'me@my.net'; 
    subj varchar2 (128) := 'Тест кирилические символы'; 
    mesg varchar2 (255) := 'Символы: Абвгдейка';  
    conn utl_smtp.connection;
    smtpServ constant varchar2 (64) := 'smtp.my.net';
    smtpFrom constant varchar2 (64) := 'oracle@my.net';
begin
    conn := utl_smtp.open_connection (smtpServ);
    utl_smtp.helo (conn, smtpServ);
    utl_smtp.mail (conn, smtpFrom);
    utl_smtp.rcpt (conn, rcpt);
    utl_smtp.open_data (conn);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'Subject: =?UTF-8?B?'||utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (
        utl_encode.base64_encode (utl_raw.cast_to_raw (subj)))||'?='||utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'MIME-version: 1.0'||utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8'||utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'||utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'From: '||smtpFrom||utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, 'To: '||rcpt||utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn,  utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.write_raw_data (conn, 
        utl_encode.quoted_printable_encode (utl_raw.cast_to_raw (mesg)));
    utl_smtp.write_data (conn, utl_tcp.crlf);
    utl_smtp.close_data (conn);
    utl_smtp.quit (conn);
end;
/
```

Результат в почтовом клиенте, и как выглядит в сыром виде:

```
-------- Forwarded Message --------
Subject:    Тест кирилические символы

Символы: Абвгдейка

-------- Message Source --------
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0KLQtdGB0YIg0LrQuNGA0LjQu9C40YfQtdGB0LrQuNC1INGB0LjQvNCy0L7Qu9GL?=
MIME-version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=D0=A1=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=8B: =D0=90=D0=B1=D0=B2=D0=B3=D0=B4=
=D0=B5=D0=B9=D0=BA=D0=B0
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое за ответ, уже разобрался проблема была с nls_lang, чуть позже напишу свой собственный развернутый ответ, возможно кому-то поможет.

Comment: Не спешите с ответом. Если проблема была связана с  nls_lang, то [ответ уже давно есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/956206/217579).

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем напишу кратко, проблема была в том, что Oracle во всяком случае версия 19c при установке в среде Windows не задает nls_lang специфичный для среды, в которой устанавливается и при подключении из клиента, в данном случае SQLPlus, к базе в кодировке AL32UTF8 принимается значение по умолчанию как AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 в результате от sqlplus из под Windows данные идут как из cmd в кодировке cp866, а Oracle сервер воспринимает их как  AL32UTF8, при этом нормально создаются таблицы с русскими буквами в названии и в названии столбцов, спокойно заносятся значения в таблицы с русскими буквами и все может нормально отображаться. Только спустя какое-то время при решении некоторых задач, как например отправка почты средствами СУБД, может всплыть проблема, что например русские буквы, нормально не отображаются в сообщении. Вообщем необходимо, проверять сразу после установки проверять значение переменной окружения nls_lang и при необходимости устанавливать его в нужное значение, для Windows 10 например это RUSSIAN_RUSSIA.RU8PC866 для каждого клиента, прежде чем заносить данные в базу.